# PUT with 'superagent' module

Tags: node.js, put, superagent

Reading [`Superagent`](https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#post-/-put-requests) documentation, There is no distinguish between POST & PUT request :

```
  request.post('/user')
    .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    .send('{"name":"tj","pet":"tobi"}')
    .end(callback)
```

How to do PUT request using this package ?

Comment: from docs: "DELETE, HEAD, POST, PUT and other HTTP verbs may also be used, simply change the method"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> DELETE, HEAD, POST, PUT and other HTTP verbs may also be used, simply change the method name.

So,

```
request.put('/user')
    .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    .send('{"name":"tj","pet":"tobi"}')
    .end(callback)
```